# System.NotSupportedException error in compact framework pictureBox control. How do I make a picture button in Compact framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm trying to make a picture button in the compact framework.  I made a usercontrol and added a picturebox.  I saw you could over ride the text and font for normal windows forms. but don't seem able to do it for compact.  It crashes VS2008.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/) from OpenNETCF.  Whenever I've tried to do custom UI and the compact framework has let me down, SDF has usually already "fixed" it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, we are already using that to optain the MAC address.  I'm really surprised how much was left out of the compact framework.